# Deploying CDN through google cloud deployment manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jinja2, cdn, google-deployment-manager

I am trying to deploy the Google Cloud CDN with my current deployment files which are `.yaml` and `.jinja`. I am struggling to find any documentation for this to be possible through the use of these deployment files.

Is the deployment of a CDN in my cloud environment restricted to the UI and command line?

Comment: Google Cloud CDN is deployed as part of a Load Balancer and not as a seperate service.

Comment: So CDN can be deployed within a deployment file as an addition to a load balancer deployment? How could this be made possible? @JohnHanley

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you cannot deploy CDN using the Cloud Deployment Manager, at least not at this time.

Cloud Deployment Manager supports deploying resources **only for a subset** of the Google Cloud Products, specified either by [resource type](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types) or by [GCP type providers](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-gcp-types).

Presently I do not see CDN listed in the list of supported products in either category. And I only see `CONSOLE` and `GCLOUD` tabs as deployment options in [Enabling Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-cdn#enable), no mentioning of Cloud Deployment Manager.