# GCP Cloud Deployment Load Balancer Backend Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

How to deploy a web page architecture from a GCP Cloud Deployment yaml, which includes static files in a storage and a load balancer that has a backend bucket connected to this storage?

We need the load balancer to connect it to the GCP CDN.

Comment: Howdy ... can you elaborate on what you mean by a "web page architecture"?  I am thinking that a GCS bucket can host your static files and at that point you have a "web page architecture" ... but there should be no need for a load balance as GCS is just "there" already.  What are you load balancing too?  Do you have back-end logic such as Compute Engines or Cloud Functions?  If so ... then a generic GCP Deployment Manager yaml isn't likely to assist.

Comment: Hi Kolban, we need the load balancer to connect it to the GCP CDN. I will update the question.
Thx

Comment: Could your question be a duplicate of ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55089580/deploying-cdn-through-google-cloud-deployment-manager

Comment: Aha!!  A trick I use when building Deployment Manager scripts is to ask how would I do this with just GCLOUD.  It appears that the gcloud recipe uses gcloud compute backend-services update [BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME] \
    --enable-cdn  .... note the "--enable-cdn".  This then takes me to https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/backendServices and I see that enableCDN is the corresponding property and THAT can be used in the Deployment Manager script.

Comment: Here you have a guide on how to add Storage buckets to load balancers - https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/adding-backend-buckets-to-load-balancers . Am I getting this right ?

Comment: as you can see from using gcloud, building a load balancer is not a single resource but actually many individual resources. Each gcloud command is a single API call, each of those API calls needs to be configured as separate resources in the deployment manager config file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to create the resources based on google's [API](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types) on the deployment manager YAML script.

As my understanding you need to connect a *load balancing* with a *backend bucket*, 
and the latter connect it to a *storage bucket*. I will asume the bucket creation is not necessary.

So the resources you need are `compute.beta.backendBucket` and the `compute.v1.urlMap`. The YAML file will look -kind- of this:

```
resources:
- type: compute.beta.backendBucket
  name: backendbucket-test
  properties:
    bucketName: already-created-bucket
- type: compute.v1.urlMap
  name: urlmap-test
  properties:
    defaultService: $(ref.backendbucket-test.selfLink)
    hostRules: 
    - hosts: ["*"]
      pathMatcher: "allpaths"
    pathMatchers:
    - name: "allpaths"
      defaultService: $(ref.backendbucket-test.selfLink)
      pathRules:
      - service: $(ref.backendbucket-test.selfLink)
        paths: ["/*"]
```

Note that the `names` are completely up to you. Also see there are `ref` (from reference) to link the `backendBucket` created on the first step to the `urlMap` of the second one.

Is good to mention that you will probably need more resources for a complete solution (specifically the *frontend* part of the load balancer).

Hope it can help in some way,
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/adding-backend-buckets-to-load-balancers) from Google on how to create a Load Balancer to serve static content from a bucket. Note that the bucket and its content must already exists, the content will not be created by DM.

Follow the `gcloud` steps, not the `console` steps. For each step, find the [correct API call](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types) and create a separate resource in your deployment manager config for each step.